# SQL: How to decrease the statement execution time?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm not an expert in SQL, i have an sql statement  :

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id IN
(SELECT distinct(content_id) FROM contents_by_cats WHERE cat_id='$cat')
AND permission='true' AND date <= '$now_date_time' ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Table `contents_by_cats` has 11000 rows.

Table `articles` has 2700 rows.

Variables `$now_date_time` and `$cat` are php variables.

This query takes about 10 seconds to return the values (i think because it has nested SELECT statements) , and 10 seconds is a big amount of time.

How can i achieve this in another way ? (Views or JOIN) ?

I think JOIN will help me here but i don't know how to use it properly for the SQL statement that i mentioned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JOIN` is exactly what you are looking for. Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT articles.* 
FROM articles 
JOIN contents_by_cats ON articles.article_id = contents_by_cats.content_id
WHERE contents_by_cats.cat_id='$cat'
AND articles.permission='true' 
AND articles.date <= '$now_date_time' 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

If your query is still not as fast as you would like then check that you have an index on articles.article_id and contents_by_cats.content_id and contents_by_cats.cat_id. Depending on the data you may want an index on articles.date as well.

Do note that if the `$cat` and `$now_date_time` values are coming from a user then you should really be preparing and binding the query rather than just dumping these values into the query.

Comment: Yes i tried it, it took 12 seconds, what do you mean by `index` ?

Comment: Hmmm, increasing from 10 to 12 seconds isn't a good enough performance improvement for you? :-)

Comment: Creating an index is a very basic part of setting up a database. Any column that you will use to regularly look something up will benefit from creating an index on that column. It's kind of like having a bunch of index cards (rows) and putting them in alphabetical order to speed up your ability to find them. What are you using to set up your database? phpMyAdmin or straight SQL or what?

Comment: It took 2 seconds more than my nested statement!, are you serious ?

Comment: The use of the 3 characters `:-)` is often intended to inject humor. In this case self-deprecating humor.

Comment: In phpMyAdmin you look at the structure of the table (looking at the list of columns) and then click on either "PRIMARY" or "UNIQUE" or "INDEX" by the column on which you wish to create an index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74039/discussion-between-fadi-obaji-and-peter-bowers).

Answer (score 1):

This is the query we are starting with:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM articles a
WHERE article_id IN (SELECT distinct(content_id)
                     FROM contents_by_cats
                     WHERE cat_id ='$cat'
                    ) AND 
      permission ='true' AND
      date <= '$now_date_time'
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Two things will help this query.  The first is to rewrite it using `exists` rather than `in` and to simplify the subquery:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM articles a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM contents_by_cats cbc
              WHERE cbc.content_id = a.article_id and cat_id = '$cat'
             ) AND 
      permission ='true' AND
      date <= '$now_date_time'
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Second, you want indexes on both `articles` and `contents_by_cats`:

```
create index idx_articles_3 on articles(permission, date, article_id);
create index idx_contents_by_cats_2 on contents_by_cat(content_id, cat_id);
```

By the way, instead of `$now_date_time`, you can just use the `now()` function in MySQL.

Comment: Okay, and should i assign a `Primary Key` too ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, 20+ years ago (when I was doing my last professional developing) it was frowned on to use sub-queries. In almost every case we found that they hurt performance. Now I'm seeing everybody's doing them and finding actual improvements in performance. Got any articles that will help me get up to speed on when to use JOIN and when to use sub-queries?

Comment: @PeterBowers . . . I can empathize.  I to learned that correlated subqueries and `like` were bad (among other things) and have had to learn that SQL optimizers have gotten better over time.

Comment: @FadiObaji . . . How long did this version take?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the two answers are correct, i just needed to apply indexes to the tables, it took less than a second. Thanks.